# Failed to update "Operating System Updates"

Tags: updates

Have been getting this issue in the last few updates. Could someone please help?[image]

Comment: Is it possible your book is full? https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu Or that the update is corrupt? https://askubuntu.com/questions/285691/is-it-possible-to-clean-the-apt-cache-from-the-command-line